# How to create a text file of size N kilobytes with repetitions of "Hello World"

Tags: python

I want to create a text file of size N kilobytes with repetitions of "Hello World" where N is specified via a config file in a different directory from the repository, with the help of python. I am able to display the hello world N number of times, where N is a numerical input from a config file, but I dont know anything about size. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import ConfigParser
import webbrowser
configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
configParser.read("/home/suryaveer/check.conf")
num = configParser.get('userinput-config', 'num')
num2 = int(num)
message = "hello world"
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write(message*num2)
f.close()
```

Comment: I do wonder why you want to do this. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Hello jorijnsmit, it is a part of my assignment and I am trying to acomplish it, since I am new to programming so I want to get the clear explanation of the solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to be clear on difference between number of characters written and number of bytes. In many encodings one character occupies more than 1 byte. In your example, if phrase is in English ('Hello world') and default encoding is `utf-8`, the numbers will be the same, but if you enable other language with different character set, they may differ.

```
...
with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:  # binary because we need count bytes
  max_size = num2 * 1024  # I assume num2 in kb
  msg_bytes = message.encode('utf-8')
  bytes_written = 0
  while bytes_written < max_size:  # if you dont need breaking the last phrase
    f.write(msg_bytes) 
    bytes_written += len(msg_bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

A string with length of 1 is 1 byte (as long as it is utf8).
That means that the size of "Hello World" in bytes is `len("Hello World")` = 11 bytes.

To get ~N kilobytes, you can run something like this:

```
# N is int
size_bytes = N * 1024
message = "hello world"
# using context manager, so no need to remember to close the file.
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
  repeat_amount = int((size_bytes/len(message))
  f.write(message * repeat_amount)
```

Comment: Note: the test.txt will contain 1 line with the size of N Kilobytes.
You can add '\n' if you need `repeat_amount` of lines

Comment: Just a note following on what @kerbelp has said, `\n` takes up 2 bytes in Python (UTF-8), so you may find huge differences in the iterations of `hello world` in both files (Though the absolute file size will remain the same)

Answer (score 2):

First get the size of your `message` and bear in mind that strings in Pyhton are objects, so when you call `sys.getsizeof(message)` this is not the pure string but the object itself. Then just count how many time you need to repeat the pure `message` to get `N` Kb as follows:

```
import sys

N = 1024 # size of the output file in Kb
message = "hello world"

string_object_size = sys.getsizeof("")
single_message_size = sys.getsizeof(message) - string_object_size

reps = int((N)*1024/single_message_size)

f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write(message*reps)
f.close()
```